# Problems with response.redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, iis-7, web

I have a very basic test page, with a button and on the button click a call to

`Response.Redirect("b.aspx")` This works fine when the page is loaded as http://myhost/index.aspx. However when the same page loads via http://myhost/, the redirect doesn't work (the same page just reloads like a normal postback).

The server is IIS7 running ASP.NET4.

I have also tried `Response.Redirect("~/b.aspx")`? And still no soup?

Comment: What's the problem you're having, is it an exception, yellow screen, mis-directed outcome, ...?

Comment: do you happen to have a default.aspx that has the same layout as index.aspx? your http://myhost/ could be loading default.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Response.Redirect("...", true);`

It won't let the rest of the code run on the page, and the rest of the code might be a server transfer from the root to the welcome page, which is messing you up.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try to set a default page. In visual studio, go in the property pages of your project, in start options, select the start action to a specific page to to your index.aspx. This way, when you access with http://myhost/, it will go to http://myhost/index.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce your behavior. I have written two aspx pages that you described and when i click button on index.aspx page, I'm redirected to b.aspx no matter if I access page as http://localhost/index.aspx or just http://localhost/ (after I set index.aspx as default document in IIS). So it must be some kind of mistake or problem with IIS configuration.

I would suggest to ensure in debugger, that Response.Redirect() is really executed and use tool such as Fiddler to inspect response headers.

Comment: I am currently working on an asp.net website and was not able to reproduce the issue either.